# How to set a GUID field from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, guid, sqldatasource

There is a parameter in InsertParameters. When I try to set it I get an error::

> Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to uniqueidentifier is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Here is my code in c#:

```
String complexID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["PKComplexID"].DefaultValue = complexID;
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: try: SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["PKComplexID"].DefaultValue = Guid.NewGuid();

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `SqlDbType` on `Inserting`:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserting(object sender, 
  SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) { 
    SqlParameter insertedKey = 
      e.Command.Parameters["@PKComplexID"] as SqlParameter; 
    insertedKey.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier; 
}
```

**References**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1712791.aspx/1:

> Object is incorrect type for uniqueidentifier field. But unfortunately
>   we do not have uniqueidentifier in VisualStudio designer. So its
>   giving you type Object. Neither you can make it uniqueidentifier which
>   throws you exception. So you have to change this parameter type form
>   code behind file in dataSource_Inserting event. Be sure its Inserting
>   event. There you can get any parameter and set the  uniqueidentifier
>   fields type to uniqueidentifier.

[GUIDs and DataSource Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2006/10/10/GUIDs-and-DataSource-Controls.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this yet, but my first reaction is:

```
Guid complexID = Guid.NewGuid();
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["PKComplexID"].DefaultValue = complexID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not convert to string. Fix your code like this:

```
Guid complexID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the parameter type from object to string. it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
Guid id=Guid.NewGuid();
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server>MapPath("Your Path"+id+fileName ));
```